Can I give different delays for different parameters while using BLE
I'm working with the BLE transmission. I have to transmit 4 to 5 parameters at the same time but with different delays. Can I do this?. Is anyone have any idea? Here is my part of code to transmit parameters.
    dataIndex = snprintf(dataBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE,
                     "S.No:%d,RawData:%.2f,EstimatedValue:%.2f,Temperature:%.2f,HeartRate",
                     serialNumber, data, filteredData,objTemp,BPM);

Here I want to send the RawData and EstimatedValue in delay(100), Temperature with delay(100), HeartRate with delay(10) or with no delay.
How to do this?

I don't understand "at the same time with different delays". This is contradictory.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
